# Does the IBM Worklight HTTP Adapter send/support sending a User-Agent header?

Tags: http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst, user-agent

Do IBM Worklight HTTP Adapters (in 6.1) send a **User-Agent** header by default when invoking a back-end service using `WL.Server.invokeHttp`? What is it's value? Assuming the answer is no, can we add one?

Comment: Andrew, if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: Idan, thanks, but what I was hoping for was the actual header value itself :) Once I get a chance to try this out, I'll add that as answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the adapter you can get the user agent the client sent like this:

```
var clientRequest = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
var userAgent = clientRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

If you then want to pass this header along to a backend service:

```
var input = {
    method :'get',
    path : 'your/path',
    headers: {
        "User-Agent" : userAgent,
    }
};

var result=WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke an adapter procedure, you can inspect the network using a tool such as Wireshark. There you will see that a User-Agent header is sent. This header is automatically added by the underlying Apache HTTPClient.

That said, you can add your own headers. [Per the user documentation for `WL.Server.invokeHttp`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23invokeHttp):

```
Parameters:  
options - The invokeHttp function accepts the following JSON block of parameters:  
...  
...  
...  
headers. Optional. Defines the headers for the HTTP request.
```

For example:

```
var input = {
        method : 'get',
        headers: {foo: 'bar'},
        path : '/mypath'
};  
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

As for its value, it may not have any value for you. It is just part of the standard.
See here for more (or google for additional information): [HTTP request header: UserAgent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069533/http-request-header-useragent-variable)