# Worklight Adapter Override Origin of request

Tags: http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Worklight 6.1

Using Chrome to test backend access API's and in one scenario the ability to override the Origin is needed to successfully issue the request and avoid a status 403.

Implementing the same API in a Worklight http adapter I would like to override the Origin to avoid
hitting a 403.   It is possible to override the Origin in a worklight http adapter.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Did not try this myself as I don't have an application doing what that yours is doing, but you can add headers to adapter requests. So, try what that is described in this question: [Does the IBM Worklight HTTP Adapter send/support sending a User-Agent header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569335/does-the-ibm-worklight-http-adapter-send-support-sending-a-user-agent-header)

```
var input = {
    method : 'get',
    headers: {foo: 'bar'},
    path : '/mypath'
};  
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Where foo:bar will be the Origin header and whatever its value should be.