# How to know the remote user uses a concrete Windows domain name

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I'm trying to develop a Java Web App to know if an user that access to the server is using a computer configured with a concrete Windows domain.

What I need to know is the name of the remote domain, as the value I get with this:

```
System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The domain name is not the same as the OS the person is running... I don't think the domain name is sent in the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) from the `header` of the user's HTTP request:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

And there you have all the info you need: OS, browser, etc.

You can rely on these links for better understanding of the `User-Agent` info:

- [Understand the user-agent string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [User-Agent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069533/http-request-header-useragent-variable)

**EDIT**

What you could do in order to retrieve the user's domain name is:

- retrieve the IP address from the request (use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet) answers as a starting point)
- after having the host's IP address, you could retrieve the host's domain name like its explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10554447/1346996)

Comment: With this I only can know if user is connecting from a Windows system, but I can't know the domain's name

Comment: @CarlosDurán, please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @aribeiro, but this solution only works if the computer is connected directly to the LAN; but if it is connected through a VPN connection, I only can retrieve the IP, not the domain (or the workgroup).